# Why do I care which gitlab runner runs my pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab-ci.yml file which I have inherited.  And I have a local gitlab server running on my laptop. I have managed to create several gitlab runners and kickoff this inherited pipeline -- which gets immediately stuck.  The error I am getting is:

...because you dont have any active runners online or available with any of these  tags assigned to them: sometag

I have pieced together that the gitlab-ci.yml file references several tags and if there is a runner with a given tag, the runner will pickup my pipeline --- but why do I need this control (or hassle, more like it).  What does it matter which runner runs my pipeline?  Do i need to closely examine the gitlab-ci.yml file and based on that make some special runner for it ?

After I have modified my runners and gave them the missing tags, I am still getting the same error. Looking at the runner API results, the results do show that where it says "online" it shows "null".   What does it mean?  How do I make this runner "online"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There may be several runner, which will have different executors set up and thus, have different functionalities. So, the best practice is to give `tags` in gitlab-ci.yml file to run the jobs on particular runner.

In order to bring your runner online, you can go in the server where that particular gitlab runner is installed, and in the restart the gitlab-runner service using `gitlab-runner restart` with the user you have installed the runner or root user.

Sometimes, it might happen that you have changed the tags or added some tags to the runner using Gitlab UI but the same tags has not been saved in `config.toml` file. (`config.toml` file stores the gitlab-runner configurations. More details here https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html)

So, in this particular case, you have to go the server where the gitlab-runner is installed, and modify the `tags` in `config.toml` file and then restart the gitlab-runner service. If everything goes well, you can see the runner is online in Gitlab UI.